# Can '%VALUE%' be written so it gets current year automaticlly

Tags: sql, mysql, wildcard, sql-like

The query looks like this:
**Datatype for month.ty is text**

```
month.ty LIKE '%2024%'
```

I am trying to make it **get year without having to change it when year ends**. Like get current year.

I have tryied with plus special character:

```
month.ty LIKE '%' + YEAR(current_timestamp) + '%'
```

This way it pops an error what ever I put inside the plus characters.
Error is: **Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '%'**

Also like this:

```
month.ty LIKE YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

**In this case it returns nothing.** But this is probbaby since it does not go into comparing cause there is no wildcard sign '%'.

And also like this:

```
month.ty LIKE '%' + CAST(year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS varchar) + '%'
```

In this case it throws an error **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

Also tryed:

```
month.ty LIKE '%' + YEAR(GETDATE()) + '%'
```

Throws error **#1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100421. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error**

I am not sure if I am missing something or there is some other way for it to work.
XAMPP version is 8.1.6-0
/ Server version: 10.4.21-MariaDB

Comment: What do you want to do there? Checking a year with `LIKE` looks incorrect to me. Could you please show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @JonasMetzler the query gets data that is in year written inside '%2024%'.
So lets say I need all the stuff that happened in 2024 without stuff from past years, there is where this LIKE operator comes on. It filters all stuff from this year and don't includes ones from other years.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: Hi - what’s the datatype for month.ty? If it’s not a date/timestamp please update your question with sample data for it

Comment: @Jens the data is text

Comment: Don’t store dates as text. Store ist as a date or timestamp. Please share the DDL and sample data.

Comment: @Jens the problem is this database is really old and I can't mess with it without braking it. Trust me I would change it if I could. :P

Comment: all your problems are because you are trying to mimic date functions manipulating text. Dates should be always put in date or timestamp field

Comment: Sample data for month.ty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's not advisable to keep dates in a text format. Instead, always use a date or timestamp type.

The problem with your query is that you're attempting to concatenate strings using the operator `+`, when you should be using the `CONCAT()` function instead :

```
WHERE month.ty LIKE CONCAT('%', YEAR(current_timestamp), '%')
```

Comment: Ohhh ok, I get it now. I found a question/answer, while trying to make it work, with + operator and tough it goes similar with that. Did not know about a CONAT at all, but thanks so much!

Comment: @Beansolder concatenation varies for different database systems; some use `+`, some `||`, some `CONCAT()`.  there are a lot of areas where you need to find questions/answers specific to your database

Comment: @Beansolder - if you not use a timestamp or datetime datatype you must always use LIKE '%xxx%' in your query. But this NEVER use an INDEX. it a FULL TABLE SCAN. And if you have.
And this gets slower with the number of rows, because MySQL always has to read all the rows and also compare them.

Another option is to add another field as a virtual column, which then automatically always contains the date. You can also use an index, but this is only possible if the string is always in the same position or you can find it. You can post an example